# Why does AirPort Utility support file sharing?

Tags: file-sharing, airport

The AirPort utility app for the iPhone allows you to share documents between a computer and an iOS device.

[image]

What kind of documents, if any, would I share between my Mac and the AirPort utility app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so that you can load configuration profiles. Say you want to set up a campus network where all the base stations have the same network name, admin password (or printing password or iCloud accounts).

This will allow you to make a copy of a configuration and load it from iOS to a computer or the other way for standardized setup.